# Does ADO.NET eliminate the need for database drivers?

Tags: database, ado.net, driver

Does using the ADO.NET Provider that a DB vendor wrote eliminate the need to have any database drivers installed on the machine?

I'm a bit confused on how ADO.NET actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ADO.Net provider *is* a database driver.

However, ADO.Net providers are (hopefully) purely managed, so they don't need any installation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how they wrote the provider. The provider can be written to include any driver, but it could also be written to expect to talk to a driver that is installed on the machine separately.

For example, Microsoft's own Sql Server provider still expects you to have the "native client" installed on each machine. But system.data.sqlite includes all that as part of the provider for the sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

There are Ado.NET providers specific to database which are tailored versions of DB drivers.
Eg: **SQLClient** -tailored version for SQL server family
    **iAnywhere**  -tailored version for Sybase db.

And we have ODBC drivers in Ado.NET which is not specific rather generic driver available out of the box.

Comment: So if I'm building a .NET WebForms app and I include the provider assembly in my project, is there anything else I should need for data access?

Comment: @Frankie: Please read more about data provider and how ado.net abstract the data access logic. I have provided another link on few examples on data retrieving and modification. If still you have issue in achieving data access then do post.  (1)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx (2)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254937.aspx